# How to convert hostname to DNS name?

Tags: c, dns

I am trying to make program that converts hostname to DNS name.

So if I have www.google.com I want to convert it to 3www6google3com0

I tried with this code but it doesn't work . Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
 unsigned char *a,niz[65536];
unsigned char host[]="www.google.ba";
a=(unsigned char*)&niz[12];
int lock = 0 , i;
    strcat((char*)host,".");

    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen((char*)host) ; i++) 
    {
        if(host[i]=='.') 
        {
            *a++ = i-lock;
            for(;lock<i;lock++) 
            {
                *a++=host[lock];
            }
            lock++; 
        }
    }
    *a++='\0';
printf("%s\n",a);
return 0;
```

When I try to print it in terminal is shows me blank space.

Comment: `strcat((char*)host,".");` - `host` only has 14 bytes (13 for your string and one for the null terminator), so you're invoking undefined behavior here (writing past your allocated buffer).

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could explain me a litle bit more what are you trying to say. Thank you

Comment: You're creating an array of `unsigned char` (which is unnecessary BTW, for regular strings just use `char`) and initializing it with the string literal `www.google.ba`. By using `[]`, you tell the compiler it should determine the size of the array for you, and it does just that: 13 bytes for the string and one more for the null terminator, 14 altogether. Then you try to _append_ to that string with `strcat`, but there isn't enough room (since only 14 bytes have been allocated).

Comment: I understand.. Can you suggest me what should I change here and how will I allocate enough space. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `unsigned char` using `char`. Using tools like `strtok` to tokenize the original string. `sprintf` to convert int to c-type string.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *a,niz[65536];
   char host[]="www.google.ba";
   a=( char*)&niz[20];

   strcat(a," ");
   char * token = strtok(host,".");
   char  buffer[20];
   while( token != NULL)
   {
       int len= strlen(token);
       sprintf(buffer,"%d",len);
       strcat(a,token);
       strcat(a,buffer);

       token=strtok(NULL,".");
   }
    *a++='\0';
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

O/P
www3google6ba2

**Edit:**

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *a,niz[65536];
   char host[]="www.google.ba";
   a=( char*)&niz[21];

   strcat(a," ");
   char * token = strtok(host,".");
   char  buffer[20];
   while( token != NULL)
   {
       int len= strlen(token);
       sprintf(buffer,"%d",len);
       strcat(a,token);
       strcat(a,buffer);

       token=strtok(NULL,".");
   }

    *a++='\0';
    int last_len=strlen(a);
     a[last_len-1]='0';
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

O/P
www3google6ba0

**Edit:3**
It is a hint to resolve your issue:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

  char c='0';
  printf("%d\n",c);

  c='3';
  printf("%d\n",c);

  c='3';
  printf("%d\n",c-'0');

}
```

Comment: I am programming in C and I am using Ubuntu with gcc complier and it says cstring: **No such file or directory **

Comment: I wold like to now how will I repair this so at the end of string be zero like this: ww3google6ba0

Comment: I would like to ask for one more thing.... is it possible that these numbers 3, 6 and 0 in www3google6ba0 be an integers so when I try to print it like `printf(%d",a[3])` I get 3  not 51.

Comment: @Lolipop It cant be integers since you defined a character type array, if you use `d` as formatter, it will print ascii value of the character.

Comment: I am so sorry for bothering you but I have just noticed that the result is **www3google6ba0** and IT SHOULD BE **3www6google2ba0** .... Thank you for your time!

Comment: Exchange the order of   `   strcat(a,token);        strcat(a,buffer);` I know it is not going to solve it completely, but remaining is your homework!!!

Comment: @Lolipop I added a hint as answer to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you my friend... I did it